# Blackberry: Sybase(SUP): LoginToSync: register callback

Tags: blackberry, sybase, sup

I'm new to Blackberry and Sybase and I must admit that I'm really hating the lack of info for both...

trying to write a plugin that will allow me to connect and login to my sybase.

I'm currently blocked by this line

```
SUP101DB.loginToSync("supAdmin", "s3pAdmin");
```

loginToSync returns void so ... how do I know if I succeeded with my login or not ?

the IOS version of the SUP registers a eventlistener and a callback

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onLoginSuccess:) name:ON_LOGIN_SUCCESS object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onLoginFailure:) name:ON_LOGIN_FAILURE object:nil];
```

how can I do the same with Blackberry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loginToSync() tries offlineLogin first. If offlineLogin fails, it will try onlineLogin. This is the recommended login method. I am not pretty sure about the exception type, you get if it fails.  But i guess it throws the ULjException exception from synchronize() method, which is present in SUP MBO generated code.